# apollo-fetch ends up in network error for a simple garphql query

Tags: angularjs, node.js, graphql

I am using `apollo-fetch` to fetch a `graphql` data.
I am ending up in a script error and the request does not go through. I an not sure what is going wrong in a fairly simple request like this. Please help.

Here's the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network request failed to return valid JSON
    at throwHttpError (apollo-fetch.js:41)
    at apollo-fetch.js:141
    at <anonymous>
    throwHttpError @ apollo-fetch.js:41
    (anonymous) @ apollo-fetch.js:141
    Promise rejected (async)
```

Here's the code:

```
const { createApolloFetch } = require('apollo-fetch');

PlayService.prototype.getPlays = function(playID) {
  const fetch = createApolloFetch({
    uri: 'graphql'
  });

 const playQuery = `query ($playid: String) {
   plays(id: $playid) {
    id
    items {
      nodes {
        id
        name
      }
    }
   }
 }`;
 fetch({
    query: playQuery,
    variables: { playid: playID }
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that is that your uri value is incorrect. You should provide a fully qualified uri like this

```
PlayService.prototype.getPlays = function(playID) {
  const fetch = createApolloFetch({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql'
  });
```